# Emp timeout time not saving in database

Tags: c#, sql

I am making emp time attendance register. I am using below code .. here insert query working fine and time-in successfully save in database timein field. Update query also execute successfully but databasae not updated...anyone please help for this...

```
private void checkin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source............");
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
    comm.CommandText = "insert into timeatten (id,name,timein)values('" +comboBox1.Text+"','"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox2.Text+"' )";
    comm.Connection = conn;
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully check in");
    conn.close();           
}

private void checkout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source.............");
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
    comm.CommandText = "update timeatten set timeout='" + textBox2.Text + "' where id='" + comboBox1.Text +"'";
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Checkout");
    conn.close();                   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing these two lines in checkout_Click:

```
    comm.Connection = conn;
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped you out!  If it did would you mind clicking the checkmark to mark this question as answered?